# Identifying relationships vs composition relationships?

Tags: entity-relationship

how are the two different? Since both of the relationships consist of one set of objects say A which cannot exist independently and another set of objects say B whose existence is necessary for the existence of objects in the set A.

So are the two same or are their some fundamental differences that I am missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

"Composition relationship" isn't a formal relationship type in ER. If I take it to mean a binary relationship `(a,b)` which is left-total (every a is related to some b) and in which `a->b` (an a is related to only one b), then an identifying relationship would be a specific kind of composition relationship. An identifying relationship has the form `((x,b),b)` in which `(x,b)->b`. Non-identifying composition relationships would then include cases in which the component set is identified by its own attributes.